# Unwanted Padding On Widget Areas

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

I have made a 3 column widget area on Wordpress, however it appears that there is padding. Ive amended the margin, however its still not resizing the widget area to fit inside my "sidebar".

This is my site:

www.mammacoil.com

This is my CSS

```
#footer-widgets {
display: block;
width:950px;
margin-left:-50px;
background: #000000;
}
#footer-widget1 {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#footer-widget2 {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
#footer-widget3 {
width: 260px;
float: left;
margin: 15px 10px 10px 15px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

***THIS IS NOW RESOLVED***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used id `footer-widget1` twice, which [isn't valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635558/multiple-identical-ids-in-the-same-html-document).

I recommend taking the id off the inner `#footer-widget1` and applying a different style.

This will resolve your padding issue.

Comment: Hi curt, Thanks for this, ive actually managed to resolve. The person in the tutorial had wrapped the area in the area twice, therefore doubling up. Ive just removed those wraps and it works fine. Thanks for the feedback